# Escrever em Retângulo - HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estou usando o seguinte código

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 55;
canvas.height = 20;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Ele gera um retângulo 55x20 px vermelho.
Porém gostaria de colocar um texto dentro deste.

Tentei `fillText();` porém sem resultados.

Alguma ajuda ?

http://jsfiddle.net/frvfyfbL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta acrescentar isso após o `ctx.fillRect`:

```
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
...
var message = "Mensagem"; //Define a mensagem
ctx.font = '9pt Arial'; //Define Tamanho e fonte
ctx.fillStyle = 'black'; //Define a cor
ctx.fillText(message, positionY, positionX); //Desenha a mensagem
```